# How to solve the differences in bar index in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am trying to modify the following code to get the exact bar index and price of that bar index.

This works in the original code while using line.new() but when i use plot i am getting the correct price but the bar index is wrong or offseted.

Why it is happening like this? How to solve this?

What I look for:
To get the latest zig zag swing point price and bar index values.

Original Code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("ZZ", overlay=true, max_lines_count=500, max_bars_back=4900)

settings = "Settings"
zigzag_len = input.int(9, "ZigZag Length", group=settings)
show_zigzag = input.bool(false, "Show Zigzag", group=settings)
fib_factor = input.float(0.33, "Factor", 0, 1, 0.01, group=settings)

var float[] high_points_arr = array.new_float(5)
var int[] high_index_arr = array.new_int(5)
var float[] low_points_arr = array.new_float(5)
var int[] low_index_arr = array.new_int(5)

to_up = high >= ta.highest(zigzag_len)
to_down = low <= ta.lowest(zigzag_len)

trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], 1)
trend := trend == 1 and to_down ? -1 : trend == -1 and to_up ? 1 : trend

last_trend_up_since = ta.barssince(to_up[1])
low_val = ta.lowest(nz(last_trend_up_since > 0 ? last_trend_up_since : 1, 1))
low_index = bar_index - ta.barssince(low_val == low)

last_trend_down_since = ta.barssince(to_down[1])
high_val = ta.highest(nz(last_trend_down_since > 0 ? last_trend_down_since : 1, 1))
high_index = bar_index - ta.barssince(high_val == high)

if ta.change(trend) != 0
    if trend == 1
        array.push(low_points_arr, low_val)
        array.push(low_index_arr, low_index)
    if trend == -1
        array.push(high_points_arr, high_val)
        array.push(high_index_arr, high_index)

f_get_high(ind) =>
    [array.get(high_points_arr, array.size(high_points_arr) - 1 - ind), array.get(high_index_arr, array.size(high_index_arr) - 1 - ind)]

f_get_low(ind) =>
    [array.get(low_points_arr, array.size(low_points_arr) - 1 - ind), array.get(low_index_arr, array.size(low_index_arr) - 1 - ind)]

[h0, h0i] = f_get_high(0)
[h1, h1i] = f_get_high(1)

[l0, l0i] = f_get_low(0)
[l1, l1i] = f_get_low(1)

if ta.change(trend) != 0 and show_zigzag
    if trend == 1
        line.new(h0i, h0, l0i, l0)
    if trend == -1
        line.new(l0i, l0, h0i, h0)

market = 1
market := nz(market[1], 1)
last_l0 = ta.valuewhen(ta.change(market) != 0, l0, 0)
last_h0 = ta.valuewhen(ta.change(market) != 0, h0, 0)
market := last_l0 == l0 or last_h0 == h0 ? market : market == 1 and l0 < l1 and l0 < l1 - math.abs(h0 - l1) * fib_factor ? -1 : market == -1 and h0 > h1 and h0 > h1 + math.abs(h1 - l0) * fib_factor ? 1 : market

if ta.change(market) != 0
    if market == 1
        line.new(h1i, h1, h0i, h1, color=color.green, width=2)

    if market == -1
        line.new(l1i, l1, l0i, l1, color=color.red, width=2)
```

Code to get the same using plot, but getting a wrong bar index:

```
bullCondition = ta.change(market) != 0 and market == 1
bearCondition = ta.change(market) != 0 and market == -1

var float latest = na

if (bullCondition)
    latest := h1
else if (bearCondition)
    latest := l1

plot(latest, color=color.yellow)
```

Image:

[image: https://www.tradingview.com/x/MqJ2sY65/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that.

The zigzag indicator is a repainting one. And it is dynamic. It will do some calculations and find the `x1` of the line. Each time the difference between the current bar and `x1` might be different.

`plot()` is a continuous line. It has an `offset` argument but it is applied to the whole series. You cannot go back and modify just a few points after it is drawn.

Comment: Is there any way to control the offset values of the plot line before plotting.